# MenuItem Style override single role style

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, menuitem

is there any way to override a single role style of MenuItem? I know the way to override the IsHighlighted color of MenuItem is to override the ContentTemplate. What i want is to override the ContentTemplate for Role "SubmenuItem"

```
<Style x:Key="ActionMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SubmenuItemTemplateKey2}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="???" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="???" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="???" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The {StaticResource SubmenuItemTemplateKey2} is my override ContentTemplate. For the other roles i want use the default templates of MenuItem. Is there any way to do it?

Best regards

Lutze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to override all the menu items and next trying to override it again (to set it back to default style). In this case you just need to override the menu item with role of `SubmenuItem`, so the code can be just like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ActionMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
         Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" 
         Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3"/>
        <!-- override here -->
        <Setter Property="Template" 
                Value="{StaticResource SubmenuItemTemplateKey2}"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Otherwise (following your original approach), we may need some dummy MenuItem element which has the default style. Then we can Bind the Template of whatever items to the Template of that dummy element to restore their default style.

Comment: It seems to be that the code above works good. Thank you very much. When i understand it correctly then everytime i'm not set a Template Setter in the Trigger section then the default style is automaticly using!

Comment: @Lutze you're welcome! I know you're fairly new to SO, if the answer is helpful, you should accept it (by clicking on the gray tick mark).